# Add virtual properties in Strapi

Tags: strapi

Is there a way to add virtual property in api response object ?

I tried to do this in the controller, but the values I add are not displayed in the API return.

My goal is to dynamically define the value of the virtual field according to the current day.

```js
findOne: async ctx => {
    if (!ctx.params._id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
      return ctx.notFound();
    }
    const cake = strapi.services.cake.fetch(ctx.params);
    cake.virtualproperty = "test to add value in api return";
    return cake;
}
```

ps: I try to do this in [strapi cake example project](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/tree/master/cheesecakes)

Comment: Are you trying to do this ? : [Mongoose Virtualtype](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/virtualtype.html). Maybe you don't use the right implementation, look at the bottom of the documentation.

Comment: Nope, but i haven't any idea where to implement that in strapi :'(

Comment: Why not using `prototype` like this `cake.prototype.virtualproperty = 'what I want'` ? I am new in `strapi` and I don't have tested that yet. What do you mean by virtual ? Just a custom property in return if I well understand ? It's very interesting. There is also the way to use maybe in the model `afterFetch: async (model, response, options) => {}` to add a property to the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to `await` your function.
Should be this following code:

```js
findOne: async ctx => {
    if (!ctx.params._id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
      return ctx.notFound();
    }
    const cake = await strapi.services.cake.fetch(ctx.params);
    cake.virtualproperty = "test to add value in api return";
    return cake;
}
```

Comment: I try but virtualproperty doesn't appear in api return :(